# How can i change the output order of a multi-dimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have these two arrays:

```
m1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
m2 = ["yes", "no"]
```

and I expect the following result:

```
expected-output = [["a", "yes"], ["a", "no"],
                   ["b", "yes"], ["b", "no"],
                   ["c", "yes"], ["c", "no"]]
```

This is the code that I tried:

```
array1 = []
array2 = []
m2.map { |e| m1.map {|i| array1 << i and array2 << e }}
newArray = array1.zip(array2)
print newArray
```

but my outcome is not in the right order:

```
[["a", "yes"], ["b", "yes"], 
 ["c", "yes"], ["a", "no"], 
 ["b", "no"], ["c", "no"]]
```

PS: I already used the sort method and it didn't work.

Comment: Just do `m1.product(m2)`.

Comment: For what it's worth, what you tried could be written `m1.flat_map{ |letter| m2.map{ |bool| [letter, bool] } }` or `m1.map { |i| m2.map {|e| array1 << i; array2 << e }}`. Using `product` is indeed a better solution but now you know how your code could be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you must use the Product function available on Ruby.

https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/product

```
> m1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
> m2 = ["yes", "no"]
=> ["yes", "no"]
> m1.product(m2)
=> [["a", "yes"], ["a", "no"], ["b", "yes"], ["b", "no"], ["c", "yes"], ["c", "no"]]
```

Comment: Perhaps preface with, "As @lurker suggests,".

Comment: @CarySwoveland It does, I didn't notice his answer, sorry. Anyway, this question comes from a Telegram group, I had reply there before, then I just come to put here.